# componentWillReceiveProps in Vue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vue-component

I am new pretty new to Vue, and coming from a rather React-y suburb. I am rebuilding my SideNav ("drawer") component from the latter. There, when one clicked the button (not being related to the navigation *per se*), it `setState`ed `this.state.toggle` that was tied to appropriate

```
class thePage extends React.Component {
...
    this.handleToggleClick = this.handleToggleClick.bind(this);
    this.state ={
      toggleState: false
    };
  }

// Slide out buttons event handlers
  handleToggleClick(){
    this.setState({
      toggleState: !this.state.toggleState
    })
  }

render() {

const button = <a href="#" onClick={this.handleToggleClick}>here</a>

const isOpenWithButton = this.state.toggleState;


return (
 <div>
  {button}
  <SideNav logo="logo.png" isOpenWithButton={isOpenWithButton}>
  . . .
  </SideNav>
 </div>
);
}

}

    export default SideNavPage;
```

the SideNav looks as follows:

```
class SideNav extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isThere: false,
      showOverlay: false,

    }
    this.handleOverlayClick = this.handleOverlayClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(NextProps) {
    if (this.props.isOpenWithButton !== NextProps.isOpenWithButton) {
      this.setState({
        isThere: true,
        showOverlay: true
      })
    }
  }

  handleOverlayClick(){
    this.setState({
      isThere: false,
      showOverlay: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      tag: Tag,
   ...
      isOpenWithButton,
    } = this.props;

    let isThere = this.state.isThere;
    let showOverlay = this.state.showOverlay;
    const overlay = <div class="overlay" onClick={this.handleOverlayClick}></div>


    const sidenav = (
      <Tag>
        <ul>
          {logo &&
            <li>
              <div className="logo-wrapper">
                <a href={href}>
                  <img src={logo} className="img-fluid flex-center d-block"/>
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
          }
          {children}
        </ul>
      </Tag>
    );


    return (
      <div>
        {isThere && sidenav}
        {showOverlay && overlay}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SideNav;
```

So, as you can see, clicking the button causes the `isOpenWithButton` props to change, and whenever it happens (componentWillReceiveProps), the sidenav with overlay appear.

I did some work on porting it to Vue, but as it lacks this lifecycle hook I am stuck with props. I have a following problem: clicking the button opens the overlay, but as you close it with clicking in the overlay, the Boolean prop sent by button does not change, what necessitates clicking the button twice if the sidenav has been already open. I know I must be missing a vital part in Vue logic, I just cannot grasp which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using `.sync` modifier

What you are looking for is called in vue a [.sync](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier) modifier.

> When a child component mutates a prop that has .sync, the value change will be reflected in the parent.

With this you can achive what you described:

> clicking the button opens the overlay, but as you close it with clicking in the overlay, the Boolean prop sent by button does not change

### Using a centralised store - (like vuex)

The same could also be achieved if you have a centralised state/store, in this case both of your components could rely on that state property.

See [state management](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html) on Vue documentation:

> Large applications can often grow in complexity, due to multiple pieces of state scattered across many components and the interactions between them

You could simple toogle the same property, for example:

```
$store.commit('overlayToggle');
```

Comment: Thanks, the `.sync` modifier totally worked! Much appreciated!